# How to return multiple values in a single select

Tags: mysql, row, multiple-select

I am converting data from MySQL to Postgres and in the Postgres database Telephone numbers are stored in the customer table as separate fields namely **Tel_Home**, **Tel_Work**, **Tel_Fax**, **Cellular** however in MySQL telephone numbers are stored in its own table **telnos**.

My question is how in a single select statement do I get all telephone numbers found in table **telnos**(might be Null - 4) returned in a single row as up to 4 seperate fields and not as 4 seperate records/rows

This is what I have tried to come up with but no success as there are up to 4 possible numbers stored per Customer.

```
    Select A.Name,A.surname,B1.number,B2.number
     from Customer A
    left join telnos B1 on A.telno=B1.id
    left join telnos B2 on A.telno=B2.id and B2.number<>B1.number
```

I am expecting result to be something like this

```
 Firstname, Surname ,Tel1 , Tel2,  Tel3,  Tel4
 =============================================
 Kurt       Hectic   12345  NULL   NULL   NULL
 Clark      Kent     12345  12345  NULL   NULL 
 Peter      Parker   12345  12345  NULL   12345
```

Struct of table Customer and telnos

```
  Customer  (How I want the result to be stored in new table Customer)
  ========
  Name      varchar(25)
  Surname   varchar(30)
  Tel_Home  varchar(15)
  Tel_Work  varchar(15)
  Tel_Fax   varchar(15)
  Cellular  varchar(15)

   Telnos                            Customer
   ======                            ========
   id          Integer(6)            Id        Integer(6)
   Description varchar(10)           Name      varchar(25)
   Number      varchar(12)           Surname   varchar(30)
                                     telno     Integer(6) FK of telnos
```

Comment: can you please tell what is your tables(Customer and telnos) struct ??

Comment: Customer Name varchar(25), Surname varchar (30), Tel_Home varchar(15), Tel_Work vachar(15), Tel_Fax varchar(15), Cellular varchar(15)

Comment: telnos ID integer(6), Description varchar(10), Number varchar(12)

Comment: where is table name ? :)

Comment: is the description in telnos are constant like tel1 or so ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen no the description in table telnos are whatever the user wanted to reference the telephone number as , so some are listed as work some are listed as business so there is no unique identifying value to Description.

Comment: @kishanoza , I have added the basic struct of tables to my question

Comment: @Kurt Hectic - then there is no way to handle the sequence of the phone numbers. is this ok for the output ?

Comment: yeah  i m working on it.

Comment: you mention **on A.telno=B1.id** in your query but there is no field in Customer called **telno**

Comment: @kishanoza I created additional table Customer next to telnos that reflects original Customer table, Customer table above is how I would like to store the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT c.*
, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(nr = 0 ,t.`Number`,'') SEPARATOR '') AS tel1
, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(nr = 1 ,t.`Number`,'') SEPARATOR '') AS tel2
, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(nr = 2 ,t.`Number`,'') SEPARATOR '') AS tel3
, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(nr = 3 ,t.`Number`,'') SEPARATOR '') AS tel4
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.*
    , @nr:=(@nr+1) 
    ,@nr:=IF(@lid = t.id,@nr,0) AS nr
    ,@lid:=t.id
    FROM telnos t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @nr:=0, @lid:=-1) AS INIT
) t ON t.id = c.telno
GROUP BY c.id;
```

**sample tables**

```
mysql> select * FROM Customer;
+----+-------+---------+-------+
| id | Name  | Surname | telno |
+----+-------+---------+-------+
|  1 | BERND | BUFFEN  |   123 |
|  2 | JOHN  | DOH     |   124 |
|  3 | PETER | PAN     |   125 |
+----+-------+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from telnos;
+-----+-------------+--------+
| id  | Description | Number |
+-----+-------------+--------+
| 123 | nr1         | 121    |
| 123 | nr2         | 122    |
| 123 | nr3         | 123    |
| 123 | nr4         | 124    |
| 124 | nr1         | 231    |
| 124 | nr2         | 232    |
| 125 | nr1         | 341    |
+-----+-------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

**sample query**

```
mysql> SELECT c.*
    -> , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(nr = 0 ,t.`Number`,'') SEPARATOR '') AS tel1
    -> , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(nr = 1 ,t.`Number`,'') SEPARATOR '') AS tel2
    -> , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(nr = 2 ,t.`Number`,'') SEPARATOR '') AS tel3
    -> , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(nr = 3 ,t.`Number`,'') SEPARATOR '') AS tel4
    -> FROM Customer c
    -> LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT t.*
    ->     , @nr:=(@nr+1)
    ->     ,@nr:=IF(@lid = t.id,@nr,0) AS nr
    ->     ,@lid:=t.id
    ->     FROM telnos t
    ->     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @nr:=0, @lid:=-1) AS INIT
    -> ) t ON t.id = c.telno
    -> GROUP BY c.id;
+----+-------+---------+-------+------+------+------+------+
| id | Name  | Surname | telno | tel1 | tel2 | tel3 | tel4 |
+----+-------+---------+-------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | BERND | BUFFEN  |   123 | 121  | 122  | 123  | 124  |
|  2 | JOHN  | DOH     |   124 | 231  | 232  |      |      |
|  3 | PETER | PAN     |   125 | 341  |      |      |      |
+----+-------+---------+-------+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```